# How can I write a fold expression in Unreal 5?

Tags: c++, unreal-5

I'm trying to write a variadic function template that would fold a parameter pack over an expression in UE5.

However, the compiler fails on the fold expression.

Since my function is a little complex, I tried with a much simpler one (copied from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)), but that didn't work either, so there clearly seems to be a problem with fold expressions in Unreal Engine 5.

Here are the function and the error

```
template<typename... Args>
bool all(Args ...args) {
        return (... && args);     //fails here
}

error: error C2059: syntax error: '...'
```

I'm not trying to have this function exposed in blueprint, it is just used internally in my code

This error doesn't seem to be new with UE5, someone has the same problem in UE4 : [Problems with fold expressions in c++](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/problems-with-fold-expressions-in-c/480774)

So I wanted to know if it's normal, if fold expressions aren't supported on UE.

If it is indeed possible (or should be possible), is it a bug, an error on my side or is there a special syntax or workaround?

Since fold expressions are c++ 17, and I'm using VS 2019 v.16.11.5, it does not appear to be a c++ standard compliance issue.

Comment: Does Unreal 4 support c++17?

Comment: @Vaillancourt This link seems to indicate that it does : [Coding Standard](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/epic-cplusplus-coding-standard-for-unreal-engine/) (section Modern C++ Language Syntax).

**Edit** : sorry I just realised that I didn't specified I'm using UE5; and UE5 does support C++17, some other features work just fine

Comment: Okay, what version of VS are you using? Fold expressions have been introduced in VS 15.5 according to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-170).

Comment: @Vaillancourt VS 2019 v.16.11.5, so it should be good